# Trying to add, modify, and remove objects and then print to text file

Tags: java, object

I need to create an inventory of objects that I can add, delete, and modify before printing to a txt file.  Help needed!  I am not sure if I set my object up in the correct manner or if it needs to be an array.  I have a book, but it mentions nothing of the procedures I need for objects here.

this is my vehicle object

```
package PortfolioProject;

public class Vehicle {
    // Variables
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private String color;
    private int year;
    private int mileage;

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public int getMileage() {
        return mileage;
    }
    public void setMileage(int mileage) {
        this.mileage = mileage;
    }

}
```

This is the program using the object

```
package PortfolioProject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Inventory {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);




        Vehicle automobile = new Vehicle();



        System.out.print("Make?");
        String inMake = scan.nextLine();
        automobile.setMake(inMake);

        System.out.print("Model?");
        String inModel = scan.nextLine();
        automobile.setModel(inModel);

        System.out.print("Color?");
        String inColor = scan.nextLine();
        automobile.setColor(inColor);

        System.out.print("Year?");
        int inYear = scan.nextInt();
        automobile.setYear(inYear);

        System.out.print("Mileage?");
        int inMileage = scan.nextInt();
        automobile.setMileage(inMileage);




        File file = new File("output.txt");
        // write to file
        try {
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
            output.println("Make: " + automobile.getMake());
            output.println("Model: " + automobile.getModel());
            output.println("Color: " + automobile.getColor());
            output.println("Year: " + automobile.getYear());
            output.println("Mileage: " + automobile.getMileage());
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.printf("ERROR: %s\n", ex);

    }
        scan.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: and what's the problem ?

Comment: Can you share error message that you get?

Comment: The problem is I am only outputting one object that I can not modify or delete.  I've search tirelessly over the internet for these methods based up on user input and can't seem to locate a solution.

Comment: @WilliamElias vehicle is a `class` not an object?

Answer (score 0):

Before writing in file you can check if vales are coming from the object(`automobile`) or not by using `system.out`:

```
System.out.println(automobile.getMake());
```

If not any values display, you get to know that problem is related to the class or object. Otherwise you get to know that problem with your `PrintWriter`.

After I checked your program I noticed that the reason for not writing values in the `output.txt`:

**Reason for not writing any values:**

`File file = new File("output.txt");` only holding the path of the text file. `PrintWriter` did not create file if file not exist. [read about `PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html).

**Solution:**

First add the directory wich text file exist, like below:

```
File file = new File("folder/output.txt");
```

Then you can make sure that directory either exist or not by:

```
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

All together:

```
File file = new File("folder/output.txt");
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
// write to file
try {
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
    output.println("Make: " + automobile.getMake());
    output.println("Model: " + automobile.getModel());
    output.println("Color: " + automobile.getColor());
    output.println("Year: " + automobile.getYear());
    output.println("Mileage: " + automobile.getMileage());
    output.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.printf("ERROR: %s\n", ex);

}
```